# infinity double operation resulting in infinity java/android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, double

I'm trying to do a division (double/double) and the result is Infinity. Can someone help me and explain why that's happening?

I searched some forums, but I didn't get the answer.

I have something like that:

```
public class CalculoSapIsolada extends AppCompatActivity
{
    double areaAcoX;
    double numeroBarrasX;
    double areaBarraX;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculo_sap_isolada);

        //Here is where i get the value of areaBarraX

        if(SapataIsolada.getAço()==50)
        {
            final Spinner staticSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_diametro_aço_x);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> staticAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.diametro_aço_CA_50, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            staticAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            staticSpinner.setAdapter(staticAdapter);
            staticSpinner.setPrompt("Selecione o diâmetro da armadura");
            staticSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) 
                {
                    Object item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                    if (i == 0) {
                    diametroAçoX = 0.5;
                    areaBarraX = 0.196;
                    }
                    if (i == 1) {
                    diametroAçoX = 0.63;
                    areaBarraX = 0.31;
                    }
                    if (i == 2) {
                    diametroAçoX = 0.8;
                    areaBarraX = 0.5;
                    }
                    if (i == 3) {
                    diametroAçoX = 1;
                    areaBarraX = 0.785;
                    }
                    if (i == 4) {
                    diametroAçoX = 1.25;
                    areaBarraX = 1.22;
                    }
                    if (i == 5) {
                    diametroAçoX = 1.6;
                    areaBarraX = 2.01;
                    }
                    if (i == 6) {
                    diametroAçoX = 2;
                    areaBarraX = 3.14;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }
           });
        }
    /* the value of areaAcoX is calculated previously and during the testrun it receives areaAcoX=11.36016 and the value of areaBarraX=0.5 */
    numeroBarrasX=areaAcoX/areaBarraX;

        Button calcular =(Button)findViewById(R.id.calcular_resultado);
        calcular.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
            
                //in altura.setText, areaAcoX==11.36016

                TextView altura = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.alturaTotal);
                altura.setText(""+areaAcoX);
            
                //In ladoLtopo.setText, areaBarraX==0.5

                TextView ladoLtopo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ladoL_topo);
                ladoLtopo.setText(""+areaBarraX);

                //In numBarrasX.setText, numeroBarrasX==Infinity

                TextView numBarrasX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.numeroBarras_x);
                numBarrasX.setText(""+numeroBarrasX);
            
            
        });


    }
}
```

I have some similar operations in the code that is not shown here and I didn't get the infinity error in their value.

Comment: It looks like the issue is probably that `areaBarraX` isn't _actually_ calculated before you calculate `numeroBarrasX` -- you just create a listener which _will_ set it whenever there's a click.

Comment: If you divide a positive number by zero (or a negative number by negative zero), it will result in infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Dividing by 0.0 of type double yields infinity. Perhaps there's a divide by 0.0 at this line before `areaBarraX` has been initialized:

```
numeroBarrasX=areaAcoX/areaBarraX;
```